# How to disable assemblies from being trimmed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0

My .net 6 web application is self contained and uses reflection to get classes that register services for Dependency Injection.

On my development machine, Release and Debug, everything works perfectly. After I have built and published it using Azure DevOps Pipelines, the binaries are all in the folder, but the classes that are used to help build the `ServiceProvider` aren't run and the application says that it doesn't have certain implementations registered when it falls over.

After adding a ton of logging, I can see that none of these services are added and most of my assemblies have not been loaded, however, if I called each class directly and run the methods that add the services, the assembly is loaded. I have a feeling that this has to do with the trimming of self-contained applications and I have read through some documentation that I have found about trimming, but nothing that I have tried seems to work.

I have a few questions:

1. Is trimming turned on by default?
   a. Can I turn it off?
   b. If it can't turn it off, how exactly do I use the [Trimming Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options?pivots=dotnet-6-0)? (more below)
2. If it is not turned on by default, where should I start to look to figure out why my assemblies are not being loaded?

The web app project is called `MyWebApp`, which has dependencies of the following projects (and their own dependencies):

- `MyWebApp.Data`

  - `MyWebApp.Data.Abstractions`
- `MyWebApp.Connectors`

  - `MyWebApp.Connectors.Abstractions`

I have added `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>` to the `MyWebApp.csproj` file and added `<IsTrimmable>false</IsTrimmable>` to all of my projects, but I still get the same issues.

Comment: Trimming was not the problem. I was using `DependencyContext.Default.CompileLibraries` to get the assemblies required for the application. In the self-contained application, there were no "CompiledLibraries". More info here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70438